# Spring Boot Actuators and CORS Configuration test failing because DB Props are not provided

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, gradle, spring-test

My Spring Boot application is configured with a Datasource and I have implemented CORS Configs and HttpSecurity .antMatchers for authorizing request.

The application seemed to have been working fine - i.e building and testing and launching when I put plain text db passwords in the props file.

Ever since I moved the creds into a [CREDHUB](https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/credhub/) service - the builds fail locally (`I remediated that by adding a test active profile in my gradle file which uses an uncommited props file - which actually has the plain text db user and pwd`) which uses  on Jenkins because the actuator and CORS tests started failing, as Jenkins is not configured to access CREDHUB.

So, my question is:

With this setup, the test seems to bring up the whole application, thus trying to connect to a running database - whose credentials are unavailable locally.
The test won't start properly because the datasource properties prefixed with db are not provided.
How can I start this test without bringing up the database connection?

`app.yml`

```
spring:
  datasource:
    driver-class-name: org.abc.jdbc.Driver
    username: ${db.username}
    password: ${db.password}
    url: jdbc:abc://${db.host}:${db.port}/${db.schema}
```

`ActuatorSecurityTest.Java`

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = RANDOM_PORT)
@Import(ExceptionHandlerConfiguration.class)
@AutoConfigureWebTestClient(timeout = "30000")
class ActuatorsSecurityTest {
    @Autowired
    private WebTestClient webClient;

    /***********************************************************************************************
     * ENDPOINTS: Actuator
     ***********************************************************************************************/

    @Test
    void should_allowActuatorInfoEndpoint_withoutAuthentication() {
        webClient.get().uri("/actuator/info").exchange().expectStatus().is2xxSuccessful();
    }

    @Test
    void should_notAllowSensitiveActuatorEndpoints_withInValidAuthentication() {
        webClient.get().uri("/actuator/env").header("Authorization", "Basic xxx").exchange().expectStatus().is4xxClientError();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So, I added `testImplementation 'com.h2database:h2'`  and everything came to order.

I was getting datasource dependency issue before.